# Replace all elements of a List

Tags: list, haskell, replace

I have to replace all elements in a list by the number of occurrences of that element, like if I have "Taylor Swift" the result will be [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1].

I already made the code to count the occurrences, I just know how to replace all elements by the number of they occurrence I already try:

```
ocurr :: [Char] -> Char -> Int
ocurr xs x = length(filter (x==) xs)

frequencias :: [Char] -> [Char] 
frequencias "" = []
frequencias xs = [ ocurr xs y| y <- xs]
```

and

```
ocurr :: [Char] -> Char -> Int
ocurr xs x = length(filter (x==) xs)

frequencias :: [Char] -> [Char] 
frequencias "" = []
frequencias xs = [x | y <- xs x = ocurr xs x]
```

but none of this works...
can anyone help me please?

Comment: When you say "none of this works", please give details of what goes wrong. Do you get a compiler rejection? Then please give the error message. Does it compile and run but return the wrong answer? Then give a small example of what it returns and why you say it's wrong.

Comment: You seem to have editted this after first posting, to remove an example of expected output. Also did the O.P. include a definition for `ocurr`? As the q now stands it is useless, and Willem's answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work since the return type you specify in `frequencias` is `[Char]`, whereas the frequencies are, according to your `occurr` function, `Int`s. The special clause for an empty list is not necesary (although not wrong). You thus can work with:

```
frequencias :: [Char] -> [Int]
frequencias xs = [ ocurr xs y | y <- xs ]
```

you can also make use of a simple [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
frequencias :: [Char] -> [Int]
frequencias xs = map (ocurr xs) xs
```

This thus gives us:

```
Prelude> frequencias "Taylor Swift"
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
Prelude> frequencias "taylor swift"
[2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

All this filtering could get expensive. Here's an easy fix:

```hs
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap)
import Data.Char (ord)
import Control.DeepSeq (force)
import Data.List (foldl')

frequencias :: [Char] -> [Int]
frequencias xs = force res
  where
   freq_map :: IntMap Int
   freq_map = foldl' go M.empty xs
   go fm c = M.insertWith (+) (ord c) 1 fm
   res = map (\c -> case M.lookup (ord c) freq_map of
          Just freq -> freq
          Nothing -> error "impossible") xs
```

The `force` ensures that the frequency map will be garbage collected promptly; it's not necessary or probably desirable if the result is consumed promptly.

An alternative way to prevent a memory leak is to delete keys that are no longer needed:

```hs
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap)
import Data.Char (ord)
import Data.List (foldl')

data Blob = Blob
  { total_count :: !Int
  , remaining :: !Int
  }

frequencias :: [Char] -> [Int]
frequencias xs0 = finish xs0 freq_map0
  where
    freq_map0 :: IntMap Blob
    freq_map0 = foldl' go M.empty xs0
    go fm c = M.alter f (ord c) fm
      where
        f Nothing = Just (Blob 1 1)
        f (Just (Blob x _)) = Just (Blob (x + 1) (x + 1))
    finish [] _ = []
    finish (c : cs) freq_map = case M.updateLookupWithKey (\_ (Blob tot remn) ->
      if remn == 1
      then Nothing
      else Just (Blob tot (remn - 1))) (ord c) freq_map of
        (Nothing, _) -> error "Whoopsy"
        (Just (Blob tot _), freq_map') -> tot : finish cs freq_map'
```

Comment: Yeah hmmm. This is actually quite an interesting problem to think about optimal solutions. I wonder if "delet[ing] keys that are no longer needed" (and thereby building intermediate lists) actually gives worse performance over typical data? If the input list is text in some language, distributions are likely to follow Zipf's law. Then there'll be a long tail of Chars that occur once. (Indeed in the O.P. _every_ Char occurs just once. Better to try with the old standby "Mississippi".) They only need counting once. Successively rebuilding the list to snip out elements may be just not worth it.

Comment: @AntC, not sure what you mean about rebuilding lists.

Comment: Ah, ok you meant 'delete' from the `IntMap`, where 'delete' means set to `Nothing`. I'm not sure (given I'm guessing about the pattern of input lists) whether it's worth 'heavy engineering' the `IntMap`. Is it worth building and then soon after `Nothing`ising for Chars that occur only once? Compare my second approach, where I keep the cache compact by ignoring singletons.

Comment: @AntC, I don't set anything to `Nothing`. In that context, `Nothing` deletes the key from the map. I don't understand your code, or how one can effectively ignore singletons.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison to @dfeuer's answer, here's a couple of lower-tech approaches.

1. Brute force approach. This has `O(n^2)` time complexity, for input list length `n`.

   ```
    occurrences :: Eq a => [a] -> [Int]
    occurrences xss = map (\ x -> count (== x) xss) xss

    count :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
    count _ [] = 0
    count p (x : xs) | p x       = 1 + count p xs
                     | otherwise =     count p xs
   ```

(I used English names for my functions ;-) `count` does the job of O.P.'s `ocurr`. But I've switched round the order of args to look more like `Prelude.filter`. `ocurr` is a little inefficient because `filter` builds an intermediate result to be the argument to `length`. We don't need to build that: merely count how many elements meet the predicate `(== x)`.

(I'm quite surprised there isn't already a `Prelude.count` nor `Data.List.count`.)

This is inefficient because it traverses the list for every element, even if it already 'knows' the count for that element value -- i.e. because it's already  met that element earlier in the list.

OTOH, if a large proportion of the elements occur only once, it avoids the overhead of building some sort of lookup structure.

2. Here's a version using an intermediate cache -- but only for elements known to occur more than once. Anybody like to guess what is its time complexity?

   ```
    data Cache3 a = TheList3 [a] | Cached3 a Int (Cache3 a)

    count3 :: (a -> Bool) -> Cache3 a -> (Int, Bool)
                        -- return both the count and whether it was cached
    count3 p (TheList3 xss) = ( count p xss, False)    -- reuse count from sol'n 1
    count3 p (Cached3 x c xs) | p x = (c, True)
                              | otherwise = count3 p xs

    -- don't cache if count = 1: we've just counted its only appearance so won't need it again

    occurrences3 :: Eq a => [a] -> [Int]
    occurrences3 xss = go (TheList3 xss) xss  where
      go _ [] = []
      go cc (x: xs) = c: go (if cached || c < 2 then cc else ( Cached3 x c cc)) xs  where
        (c, cached) = count3 (== x) cc
   ```

Comment: To answer @dfeuer's q/comment on his answer: datatype `Cache3` combines the cache and the input list; constructor `Cached3` conses cache entries on to the front of the list. But only cons after counting that element for its first appearance (`cached` in `go` is False) and if the count is greater than `1` (`c < 2` is false). Holding the cache as a cons-list is 'inefficient' (for searching, arguably) vs the cons operation is 'cheap' compared to inserting into an `IntMap`'s or `Set`'s BTree.